# matplotlib automatically shows figure

Tags: matplotlib

I am using `matplotlib` version `3.0.3` in Eclipse Oxygen 3 on Windows 10.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=4, ncols=4) # Figure is shown!?
plt.show() # expected to see figure only here
```

It seems that whenever a `plt` method gets called `matplotlib` already opens the UI.

That is useful while debugging but I usually want to just `savefig` and not stop to look at the generated image ...

This used to work fine for me on my previous Window 7 laptop (not sure what `matplotlib` version).

Has something changed in the default behavior which I cannot find documented?

Comment: do you happen to work with jupyter and the too commands are in two different cells?

Comment: This is not a matplotlib problem, maybe your Eclipse Oxygen version changed or uses a different setting? Do you use IPython? Did IPython version change?

Comment: @QuangHoang I am not using Jupyter.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest the Eclipse version is the same (I literally copied it from the old laptop). I am not using IPython

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stepping into the `matplotlib` code I've discovered that interactive mode was set -- probably by default as I don't have a `matplotlibrc` file anywhere.

I added `matplotlib.interactive(False)` at the beginning of `main()` to solve this. 
Apparently I still get the interactive mode when debugging even with the above line, so this is good enough for me (for now).